# Can I statically-link a dynamically-linked executable?

Tags: executable, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I've dynamically-linked an executable, `my_app`, which has some dependencies it would fill at load time, e.g. `libm.so.6`, `libpthread.so.0` etc. And - the dependencies are satisfied on the system I'm on.

Now, I want to get a statically-linked version of `my_app`, but - I don't want to do that by rebuilding it from source; I want to bake in the libraries that are currently found on my system, which allow me to run `my_app`.

Is this possible? Can this be done easily?

Notes:

- To clarify, I want to do this without using the original sources in any way; just with the executable. But if it helps, you may assume I've added debug information, or LTO enablement information or what-not.
- If it matters, assume the OS is GNU/Linux, the HW platform is AMD64, and `my_app` was written in C or C++.

Comment: Not really. You could bundle the dynamic binary in an elf section. And then load it that way. But at that point it'd be less effort to just rebuild as a statically linked binary. However it is relatively straight forward to go static-lib -> dynamic-lib. It's much harder to go the other direction.

Comment: Oh nevermind I misinterpreted your question. You can just relink your binary, as long as you have the original object files you don't have to recompile from source.

Comment: @silvergasp: Make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I statically-link a dynamically-linked executable?

No not really, but here are some alternatives that might suite your needs.

Creating a wrapper over a dynamically linked library to behave as if it were statically linked is rather challenging and only something I'd ever consider if I **didn't** have access to the source code. But going the other way i.e. static->dynamically linked library is a lot easier.

What you are describing would be better achieved by crafting your build pipeline to start with statically linkable archives/objects and then optionally transforming them into a dynamic/statically linked executables. The predicate for this is that you have access to a statically linked version of your third-party deps.

Consider the example where you have the following files;

- foo.{c/h} (depends on libmath)
- bar.{c/h} (depends on libpthread)
- main.{c/h} (depends on foo an bar)

You could build this project using the following steps;

```bash
# Compile everything as it's own object file, including your main.
clang -c -o foo.o foo.c -fPIC
clang -c -o bar.o bar.c -fPIC
clang -c -o main.o main.o -fPIC
# Create the main archive with all your internal symbols resolved.
llvm-ar r main.a foo.o bar.o main.o

# Create your dynamically linked executable (clangs default). i.e. 
# Resolve your external library symbols.
clang -o main_dynamic main.a -lm -lpthread

# Create a statically linked version. Note that we aren't recompiling from
# source rather we are changing the final stage in our build to choose a
# different linking mode.
clang -o main_static main.a -lm -lpthread -static

# Confirm we don't have any dynamic symbols.
ldd main_static
```

Something to keep in mind is that statically linking is not as well supported with linux libs as they are with dynamic so expect to run into weird errors like 'DYNAMIC_RELOC' when statically linking etc. A general thing to note as well is that when it comes to libc, it tends to be backwards compatible, but not forwards compatible. So when building your project in statically linked mode, do so on the **oldest** system that you expect to support, otherwise, you'll run into some really strange bugs, in areas where libc is interacting with the kernel i.e. syscalls.

## When you don't have static archives for third-party deps

In this case I'd highly recommend using something along the lines of ubuntu's 'snap' packager or fedoras 'flatpack' which allows you to bundle all your dynamic libs and other assets into an executable format. Think docker, but for regular executables.

## You absolutely have to wrap a dynamic library so it behaves as static

I'm going to give a brief summary here as a complete response to this would be too long form for StackOverflow. Though there is a more complete guide here ["Position-Independent Code with GCC for ARM Cortex-M"](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2021/06/05/position-independent-code-with-gcc-for-arm-cortex-m/) by Erich Styger, where he describes how to psuedo-statically link a dynamically linked executable for a microcontroller. In summary, this was the process to do so;

- Compile a dynamically linked library
- Compile your executable and link it against your dynamic library
- Write your own loader to load the dynamically linked library

  - Parse the ELF headers in your dynamic lib
  - Create a jump table that redirects calls to your dynamic lib through the global offset table (GOT).
  - Implement lazy loading so that you only initialise your GOT when you actually call a function in your dynamic lib.
- Dump the dynamic lib into an ELF section so that it is included in the same binary.

Comment: Only the first sentence of this answer, and the last section summarizing the Erich Styger post, address my question. As for the  rest  - I appreciate the sentiment in writing it down but it's not something I have a problem with. Maybe you want to post it as a separate question + answer? ... As for your last section - I really didn't understand it. I don't want lazy loading. Can't I just "load" all the dynamic libraries, like they would be loaded at run-time, but apriori?

Comment: Yeah that's fair. So the first part of loading is to just find out where all the dynamic library files are. The second stage of loading is to parse the ELF header and work out what all the offsets are for the actual functional code in the .so shared library. You then load those offsets into the global offset table (basically a lookup table). Lazy loading is where you only load the offsets the first time you use the function rather than all at once at the start of the program. This significantly reduces the startup time of your app as you aren't loading functions you aren't using.

Comment: "So the first part of loading is to just find out where all the dynamic library files are" <- ldd works :-P

Comment: Yeah that's right ldd, basically just does that first bit and then dumps the result to stdout and is effectively a command line wrapper over ld-linux.so. On linux, the loading and population of the `.got` or global offset table is handled by ld-linux.so. Which is in a predefined location and implicitly linked into each binary that uses dynamic libraries. There are multiple different loading 'modes' to populating the GOT. On linux the default is called lazy loading.

Comment: If you are interested in loading all the symbols when the program starts, or just in general the different loading modes take a look at the [docs for dlopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen). In particular search for 'RTLD_' on the man page and you'll get a full list of the loading modes.

Comment: More the point I was trying to make was that in order to psuedo-static link a dynamic library you'd need to either create your own loader or at the very least create an adapter for the linux loader.